# Convert EXE file into MSi with all its dependencies

Tags: .net, windows, exe

I have a exe file but it has got some dependencies files with it in sperate folder, and i need to make it to MSI whihc also includes those dependencies files as well so i can run it from network to all the system.
any help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to create a setup package. Here is a tutorial that should be what you need.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353

Comment: thanks michael. actually i am trying to deploy the outlook add in. and when i make the setup package from vistual files and run it on the local machine it does install all the required files to specific location but it dont make the changes in the registray and coz of that add in does not get load in the outlook.

Comment: @Ikiet, go to this site (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vishnuprasad2005/SetupProjects12022005022406AM/SetupProjects.aspx) and scroll down about 25% down the page. It will walk you through adding registry entries for the installer.